# Setting up a loadbalancer behind a proxy server on Google Cloud Compute engine

Tags: web-services, rest, proxy, load-balancing, google-compute-engine

I am looking to build a scalable REST webservice on the Google Cloud Compute Engine but have a couple of requirements that I am not sure how best to implement.

Structure so far:

2 Instances running a REST webservice connected to a MySQL Cloud database.
(number of instances to scale up in the future)

Load balancer to split request between the two or more Instances.

this part is fine.

What I need next is that the traffic (POST requests from instances to an external webservice) must come from a single IP address. I assume these requests can not route back through the public IP of the load balancer?

I get the impression the solution to this is to route all requests from instances though a 3rd instance running squid. Is this the best way to do this? (side question)

Now to my main question:

I have been reading about ApiAxle which sounds like a nice proxy for Web Services, giving some good access control, throttling and reporting capabilities.

Can I have an instance running ApiAxle followed by a google cloud Load Balancer which shares the request from the proxy to the backend instances that do the leg work and feed the response back through the ApiAxle proxy, thus having everything though a single IP visible to clients using the API? (letting me add new instances to the pool to add capacity.)

and Would the proxy be much of a bottle neck?

Thanks in advance.

/Dave

(new to this, so sorry if its a stupid question because I cant find anything like this on the web)

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean "What I need next is that the traffic (POST requests from instances to an external webservice) must come from a single IP address." Are you saying that the REST services that you are exposing make additional, external calls? Is the restriction that it must come from a single IP address a limitation of the licensing from that external service?

Comment: Its security related really, the IP must be whitelisted in the destination systems and I need to be able to rapidly scale capacity by deploying new instances and cant wait the lead time for adding new IP addresses to the Third parties systems. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to NAT on your outbound traffic so it appears to come from one IP address.  You need to do that via a third instance since Google LB stack doesn't provide this.  GCLB works only with inbound connections on the load-balanced IP.

You can setup source-NAT using [advanced routing](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/networking#routing), or you can use a proxy as you suggested.